# css grid fit rows heights

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to remove the worthless margin between rows, so I want every div takes the content height without giving margin to his side div, I tried everything but nothing works.

```css
.grids {
  width: 90%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content);
  margin: auto;
  grid-gap: 32px;
}

.grid {
  position: relative;
  width: 95%;
  height: max-content;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grids">
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
  <div class="grid"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what is needed, but for a start why is there a grid-gap setting if you don't want a gap between rows?

Comment: Adding to what @AHaworth said, you also have an additional `10px` margin for each of your `grid` element.

Comment: i want some space between columns and between the rows but i want the divs to fit the height, i don't want worthless margin-bottom

Comment: fireship.io have what i want in the bottom of there website in the section of" Loved by Developers since 2017"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** To make a masonry layout I have wrapped grid items in div tag
so you can nest as many tags as you want.

1. grid items overflow the content because of the width and height properties.
2. you're using a grid gap for both rows and columns.

So I guess this might help you out.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(120px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: masonry;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
    padding: 20px;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 10px; 
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
    <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="grid-item">
    <h1>Hello 
      <br> 
      friend
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I renamed the classes for naming purposes only.

MDN docs grid-row: [row-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap)

MDN docs masonry layout: [masonry layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Masonry_Layout)

Comment: i want the divs to fit the worthless hight, if a div contain content more then the other

Comment: Do you mean something like masonry layout?

Comment: fireship.io have what i want in the bottom of there website in the section of" Loved by Developers since 2017"

Comment: i tried to copy their code the same but it did't work with me like how it works in their website

Comment: Oh since that's the case it's fairly easy.  I will modify my answer in a few seconds and confirm if it is correct or not

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `grid-gap: 32px` to `grid-gap: 0 32px`, it will remove the margin between grid rows;